# More fitting alternative for 'air-raid'

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I wonder what one would call an alarm that is set off when the impact of a (nuclear) missile is imminent.

`Air-raid` doesn't really fit, for the bombardement is not carried out by planes but rather by a (single) missile.

Comment: Maybe Missile Alert?

Comment: I don't know. In the 1960s they used to talk a lot about *the four-minute warning*. So if it took us more than four minutes to decide what to call it, it would be too late!

Comment: I call it *futile.*

Comment: It's  a civil-defense siren.

Comment: @BrianDonovan
Assume a nuclear bunker. This is for a work of fiction.

Comment: @RK01
I tought of that one, too, but I didn't know whether or not it would be a common thing to say. I'm a non-native speaker.

Comment: @deadrat Thanks, I think I'll go with that, even though the four-minute warning sounds sort of more dramatic

Comment: @Sprottenwels I don't think anything related to a warning for a nuclear missile would be considered a common thing to say.

Comment: Presumably missiles fly through the air with their explosive payload in much the same way as airplanes do :-)

Comment: Intercontinental nuclear missiles are ballistic, which is to say nothing like nuclear bombers.

Comment: When I was a kid in the 50s the sirens and radio broadcasts were, as @deadrat says, called Civil Defense alerts.

Comment: In the 1960's and 70's, they were known as Civil Defense Sirens and they were sounded every Tuesday at 10:00 AM.  FWIW, I checked, and if we heard those sirens today, there are over 1,000 air-raid/fallout shelters available in Chicago! http://www.chicagoreader.com/chicago/which-way-to-the-nearest-fallout-shelter/Content?oid=884262

Comment: @Sprottenwels, as you mentioned this is for a work of fiction, and there seems not to be a widely used term for what you're describing, I suggest you consult your own imagination and invent or borrow a term that you feel serves the needs of your story.

Comment: To me an 'air-raid' is an attack delivery from the sky, regardless of the type of trajectory the delivery vehicle is on.  In the UK at least, I'd imagine that those pedantic enough to find a distinction were all killed by V2 bombs in the mid 1940s, when they refused to enter 'air-raid' shelters.  Hence the  distinction suffered extinction.

Comment: It's a KYAG warning -- kiss your ass goodbye.

Comment: But if it's a government-defined warning (work of fiction or not), it should be some sort of euphemism.

Comment: We have a nuclear power plant nearby, and the sirens are strategically placed atop utility poles in the area. @deadrat is right about the official terminology, but if you've ever been getting the mail out of your mailbox when they go off over your head, you may agree with my nickname: "The 'Holy Shit' Horns".

Comment: In the vein of @HotLicks, I'd call it a *death knell*.

Comment: @WS2 has it. It is a 4-minute warning: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-minute_warning

Comment: @Sprottenwels I would like **nuclear strike**. Hope that helps.

Comment: It should be noted that the "air raid" sirens around here are used for tornado warnings, and are much more strongly associated with that than with any other sort of airborne threat.  They are apparently referred to as ["Outdoor Warning Sirens"](http://www.rochestermn.gov/departments/emergency-management/resident-and-visitor-information/outdoor-warning-sirens).

Answer (score 1):

I googled with the search terms *warning systems* and I could find the following names:

**Civil defense Siren**

**Ballistic Missile Early Warning System**

**Chrysler Air-raid Siren**

**Emergency Alert systems**

**P.S.** : These systems do not necessarily sound when missile is launched from a plane. It can very well be from an over-ground unit(lack of a better word here).

**Interesting piece of information:** I hear that there are now smartphone apps available in Israel which warn people of any incoming missiles, ahead of time just like when we are about to receive a call (check the link given below). I can only imagine the dreading moment if the user put his/her cellphone on silent mode there :-)

http://www.timesofisrael.com/red-alert-app-offers-a-yo-update-on-missile-attacks/

Answer (score 0):

It is a [***Four-minute warning***](http://Four-minute%20warning)

Wikipeida:

> The four-minute warning was a public alert system conceived by the British Government during the Cold War and operated between 1953 and 1992. The name derived from the approximate length of time from the point at which a Soviet nuclear missile attack against the United Kingdom could be confirmed and the impact of those missiles on their targets.